# Need help using google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm trying to get the duration_in_traffic from google maps using google maps api, but (1) I don't understand how to get the client id and (2) I don't know what is the signature parameter. (the duration_in_traffic is the driving time considering traffic, which you can see when requesting path in google maps)
Could you help me? 
Thanks, Yuval.

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

If you search here "duration_in_traffic" you'll see google's description of it and the parameters needed which includes client and signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to purchase the [for Work](https://www.google.com/work/mapsearth/) version of Google Maps API in order to get duration_in_traffic parameter. You will be provided with a client id and a signature, which you would then use to make requests, as explained on [Web Services - Authentication and Authorization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth)